# Share button is crashing in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift

so I have a share button where it opens up UI-Activity. When I click on the share button it crashes and I receive this error: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`. can any one check my code and see what is going on? Thanks
*One last thing as well: The share button stays on the screen when they return to the game. How can I hide it, like only show it in the Game Over Scene?

> here is my code

```
    shareButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: view.frame.size.width / 3, height: 60))

//        shareButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/4, y: self.size.height/4)
        shareButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width / 2 - 70, y: view.frame.size.height / 1.275)
        shareButton.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: 3*self.frame.height/4)

        shareButton.setTitle("Share", for: UIControlState.normal)
        shareButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
       shareButton.addTarget(self, action: (#selector(GameOver.pressed(_:))), for: .touchUpInside)


//        shareButton.removeFromSuperview()
        self.view?.addSubview(shareButton) 



 func pressed(_ sender: UIButton!) {


 let va = self.view?.window?.rootViewController

 let myText = "Can you beat my score \(score) in the game of Balls"

 let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myText], applicationActivities: nil)

 va?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)




 }
```

Comment: What is `GameOver`. Is it a class?

Comment: yes it is a class

Comment: why you are not presenting that  activityVC using self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function `pressed:` is in `GameOver` class, do not add target as `self`. Instead add target as an object of `GameOver` class

```
let objGameOver = // Get your existing GameOver class instance here
shareButton.addTarget(objGameOver, action: (#selector(GameOver.pressed(_:))), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: can you please show me a code? Something like this: `shareButton.addTarget(self, action: ("pressed:"), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: objGameOver says `Variable used within its own initial value` ?

Comment: No. you should get the existing class. What is the `GameOver` class purpose here. have you already created the instance of that class? Is it a `UIViewController`?

Comment: its a `SKScene`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148027/discussion-between-bali-and-billy-jr).

Comment: maybe like this, right?  `let objGameOver = GameOver()
            shareButton.addTarget(objGameOver, action: (#selector(GameOver.pressed(_:))), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: Try that and let me know

Comment: Lets chat, I am waiting